# How can I get data from database in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, migration

I have database:

```
class CreateDataintables < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :windows do |t|
      t.string :window
      t.timestamps
    end

     create_table :channels do |t|
      t.integer :channel
      t.integer     :data
      t.belongs_to :window
      t.timestamps  
    end 


  end
end
```

I want to read / write data from/to window "test" , channel "1" but don't know what to do. Give me some example code, please .I really need it.

Comment: Why not read the rails guide? everything is there. Also a little better description would help.

Comment: Althougth I read the rails guide , I don't know how to do.I want to create some 'window' in table 'windows' then I want to create 89 channels with 89 datas in table channel -> 1 window in table 'windows' will have 89 channels. Finally, I want to create/read data from it.

Comment: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/beginning#top - that's a really good guide.  it might take you a week or so to go through it, but you'll be so glad you did =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following should be Model code:

```
Class Window < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :channels
end

class Channel < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :window
end
```

In the console, do the following:

```
@window = Window.create(window: "This is window-1")
```

This will create a windows-instance and saves it into the database.

```
100.times do |index|
  Channel.create(channel: Random.rand(1000),
                 data:    Random.rand(1000),
                 window:  @window)
end
```

This will create 100 Channel instances that belong to the earlier-created-window. Also, saves them to the database.

`@window.channels` will return the corresponding 100 channels.

This is how you write/insert record and read/fetch record.

Please do read http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#create and http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#read for better clarity and exploring futher,

Comment: I 'll do it but I only have 13rep :D

Answer (score 0):

You really need to go back to the drawing board, dude.

Most rails beginners start off with the twitter clone tutorials, at least that's what I did.

Here is a free course from codeschool.com that I used when I first started off to start working with ActiveRecord  https://www.codeschool.com/courses/rails-for-zombies-redux