# How can I get data from database in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, migration

I have database:

```
class CreateDataintables < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :windows do |t|
      t.string      :window
      t.timestamps
    end
     create_table :channels do |t|
      t.integer     :channel
      t.integer     :data
      t.belongs_to  :window
      t.timestamps
    end 
  end
end
```

Althougth I read the rails guide , I don't know how to do.I want to create some 'window' in table 'windows' then I want to create 89 channels with 89 datas in table channel -> 1 window in table 'windows' will have 89 channels. Finally, I want to create/read data from it.

Comment: Actualy a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20278307/how-can-i-get-data-from-database-in-ruby/20278868#comment30252848_20278868 . The answer for it is already posted and confirmed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20278307/how-can-i-get-data-from-database-in-ruby/20278868#20278868